# Prove largest possible eigenvalue of matrix $A(A^HA)^{-1}A$ is $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ be a matrix defined as:

> $$M=A(A^HA)^{-1}A^H$$

How can one prove that the largest possible eigenvalue of $M$ is $1$?

Comment: Do you mean $M = A(A^H A)^{-1}A^H$?

Comment: @MichaelBiro That is possible.  The original image ([seen here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G0NV9.png)) was possibly cut off at the right side.  I am unfamiliar with the specific result.

Comment: Very similiar (but not exact duplicate) to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510992/the-norm-of-aaha-1ah

Comment: @MichaelBiro: yes, you are right. The right formulation is the that you mentioned.

Comment: @IanMiller Thank you. is it possible to provide me more details?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $M^2 = A(A^HA)^{-1}A^HA(A^HA)^{-1}A^H = A(A^HA)^{-1}A^H = M$.

In other words, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$ then $\lambda \mathbf{x} = M\mathbf{x} = M^2\mathbf{x} = \lambda^2 \mathbf{x}$, so $\lambda \mathbf{x} = \lambda^2\mathbf{x}$.

Can you finish the argument?

Comment: What if $A^HA$ is singular ?

Comment: The question asks for a defined matrix $M$ that uses $(A^HA)^{-1}$, so it implies that $A^HA$ is not singular.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much Micheal